# How to load nuget packages dynamically?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, nuget-package

I have created a nuget package using unity framework and it is running well on a device. But the problem is I cannot run it on a simulator because, in unity I have set the target SDK is to "Device SDK". Either Device SDK or "Simulator SDK" can be selected at a time. So my thought is to create 2 versions of nuget package for device and simulator and dynamically load it according to the target(simulator or device). I want to know

1. Is this even possible?
2. If this is possible, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to achieve this:

First, you can override the `AssemblyResolve` event as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268(v=vs.110).aspx. This will make it possible for you to load the assembly in the right version at the time of need.

Second, you can change the `web/app.config` and here is the method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.110).aspx.